# Is there any way to supply generic arguments to a function-like proc macro?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

So let's say I have a proc macro defined like this:

```
#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream { ... }
```

Is there any way to introduce a generic argument?  For instance, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro<T>(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream { 

    ...
    T::do_something_with(input);
    ...
}
```

And at the call site:

```
my_macro::<Foo>! { some input }
```

Is there any way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible, for two reasons:

- The syntax for function-like proc macros does not include generic parameters.
- If there *was* such a thing, the generic parameters would necessarily come as annother `TokenStream` — not something you can call a function on. The types of the program where the macro is used don't exist yet — they're still being parsed.